# What do "Glad our discussions are resonating with you" mean?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, terminology

I was texting with a friend after talking with her about some topics and then she answered with:

> Glad our discussions are **resonating with** you.

What does it mean? First I thought it means that I was thinking about our discussions (so that the discussions were 'resonating' inside me) but reading here and there the possible meaning perhaps I misunderstood. 
Thank you!

Comment: Can you give a little bit more context? Why were you talking about these topics?

Comment: sure, we were discussing about the idea of freedom, just for the sake of thinking about it

Comment: This is the kind of question this site was built for.

Answer (score 2):

She probably means that she's glad your ideas agree, or that you feel the same way.

Reference: https://www.lexico.com/definition/resonate

> 1.2 US (of an idea or action) meet with agreement.
>
> *the judge's ruling resonated among many of the women.*
>
> *The ideas resonated with him because that's how he has lived his life.*